# Why my video stretching on Firefox but not on Chrome?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, html5-video

I try to make a banner video that will stretch always at 100% of the width. It works great on Firefox, but not Chrome. Why? See https://www.gustdive.com for example. I tried to use the code snippet, however, there are too much compatibility issues and it doesn't work fine. The only way that I can provide a concrete example is with my link itself.

Thanks @Mav for providing the visual example! Please see

Firefox

[image]

Chrome

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Main Layout Content -->
<md-content md-colors="accent">

    <!-- Tabs Layout -->
    <md-tabs md-selected="ctrl.tabSelected" md-stretch-tabs="always" class="md-primary" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>

        <!-- Home Tab -->
        <md-tab>

            <!-- Home Tab Label -->
            <md-tab-label>
                <h2>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="media/image/icon/home.svg"></md-icon>
                    <span hide show-gt-sm>
                        &nbsp;Home
                    </span>
                </h2>
            </md-tab-label>

            <!-- Home Tab Body -->
            <md-tab-body>

                <!-- Home Tab Banner -->
                <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" style="overflow-y: hidden; max-height: 275px; text-align: center; background-color: #000;">
                    <div id="banner-title" style="position: absolute;">
                        <img src="media/image/icon/logo-white-192x192.png" alt="GustDive Logo" />
                        <span hide show-gt-xs>
                            <br />
                            <h1 style="font-size: 50px; color: white; text-shadow: 0 0 10px white; letter-spacing: 15px;" flex>
                                GustDive
                            </h1>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <video loop muted autoplay style="width: 100%;">
                        <source src="media/video/underwater-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="media/video/underwater-360p.mp4" media="(max-width: 640px)" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>

                <!-- Home Tab Content -->
                <md-content layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-wrap>

                </md-content>

            </md-tab-body>

        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>

    <!-- Website Footer -->
    <div md-colors="{background: 'grey-A200'}" layout-padding>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.padi.com" aria-label="Padi">
                <img src="media/image/icon/padi.png" alt="Padi" />
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g150793-d11888983-Reviews-GustDive-Puerto_Vallarta.html" aria-label="Trip Advisor">
                <img src="media/image/icon/trip-advisor.png" alt="Trip Advisor" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div layout-align="center end" style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">Copyright © Jonathan-Gagne.com 2018</div>
    </div>

</md-content>
```

Comment: The snippet works find here on both browsers.

Comment: The snippet is too much small... :( Try on the website directly you might understand the issue.

Comment: If the snippet does not behave in the same way as the website, you need to update the snippet. It shouldn't be necessary to go to an external website.

Comment: If anyone wants to see the problem, https://imgur.com/a/WUMyTJc

Comment: Added your example on my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Try adding `object-fit: fill;` to your video element css.  I tried in chrome and that works, have not tried in other browsers

Comment: could also use `object-fit: unset;`

Comment: or `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: Right now you have `object-fit: contain;` on it.. which comes from user agent stylesheet - basically this is Chromes styling. You can either normalize it, or you can overwrite it

Comment: you can see chromes stylesheet here, to see what it affects. : https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#preview

Comment: Awesome all these 3 work perfectly for Firefox and Chrome. Is there anyway to make it works for Edge as well? It is actually doing the same thing then Chrome before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `object-fit: fill` to make the width 100% on Chrome. This will not work for IE11 though (see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)).

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there anyway to make it works for Edge as well? It is actually doing the same thing then Chrome before?